# Get string which contains "~" followed by 8 alphanumeric capital characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex expression which can match these files

[image]

Every file ends with "~" and 8 alphanumeric characters.

```
accueil.pop.wanadoo.fr.iaf~VBTF3DM8
AFFICHE CLASSEUR.doc~HVN67L8A
affiche maison Lèves.doc~VF7T22A6
affiche vitrine maison BIL.doc~92AI78DG
affiche vitrine.doc~9M9MO72D
ancien en-tête.doc~142EVL8F
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide the name files as text and not an image.

Comment: Use the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` character class to represent an alphanumeric character, the `{n}` quantifier to represent the fact there's `n` of them, the `$` anchor to represent the end of the string and simply `~` to represent the literal `~`, which has no special meaning in regex. That's all very basic, which might explain why your question isn't very well received (a basic knowledge of the topic is somewhat expected)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness sorry, I have editedt my question.

Comment: @user3673720 Not a problem. I have submitted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52098073/3390419) to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^[^~]+~[A-Z0-9]{8}$
```

- `^` Beginning of string.
- `[^~]+~` Anything other than a tilde, one or more, followed by a tilde.
- `[A-Z0-9]{8}` Eight alphanumerical characters.
- `$` End of string.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/8bdCXC/1).

---

Alternatively you may use:

```
^[\pL -.]+~[A-Z0-9]{8}$
```

- `^` Beginning of string.
- `[\pL -.]+` Character set. Matches any letters from any alphabet, `-`, full stops `.` and whitespace.
- `~[A-Z0-9]{8}` Matches a tilde followed by eight alphanumerical characters.
- `$` End of string.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/8bdCXC/2).

Answer (score 0):

To select file name with your expections
Try this,

```
[\w.]*~[A-Z0-9]{8}$
```

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx should do the job:

```
.+?~\w{8}
```

It select any char one or more times, followed by tilde and 8 characters.

Comment: `\w` matches lower case letters and underscores too. Also matching anything lazily `.+?` is not very efficient.